# NetBeans 12.1 Installation Error on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have `JDK 15.0.1` and I've installed `Netbeans 12.1` with it.
I am having significant trouble trying to open up a project because it gives me these error messages when I reach the section **'Finding Feature'**

```
"Cannot enable Java Persistence, Spring Beans, Gradle, Java, Java SE Modular Projects, Java Debugger, Maven, GUI Builder, GraaIVM Debugging Support"
```

I have tried every tutorial possible on here and on YouTube and I just can't seem to get past this part.

Comment: Which macOS version are you using?

Comment: Hey, I just decided to completely abandon installing the NetBeans IDE and stuck with Eclipse instead and the installation process was a billion times easier AND it's so much easier to start coding. For reference though I have the most recent version, macOS Big Sur

Comment: I suspected you were using Big Sur, but I had to ask.  I'm not a Mac user but there have been plenty of other questions about running NetBeans on macOS Big Sur here.  You are far from alone in having such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like follows:

Check where is your `netbeans.conf` file located by typing

```
locate netbeans.conf
```

Once you got your conf file location you will have to edit it by using your favourite editor like:

```
sudo nano <.../path/netbeans.conf>
```

In this file you got to change the line referring to your java installation for example:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home"
```